# Python string comparisons time complexity

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

I'm curious how Python performs string comparisons under the hood.
For example if

```py
if s1 == s2:
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

is the same as

```py
condition= True
for x,y in zip(s1, s2):
    if x != y:
        condition = False 
print(condition)
```

Perhaps under the hood python is able to use ord values more efficiently than O(n) traversals?

Comment: It's more efficient because `string.__eq__` is implemented in C and accessing the underlying C data structure, rather than going though Python's iterator protocol and repeatedly invoking `string.__eq__` on separate 1-character strings.

Comment: As an aside, you'd add a `break` to that second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's string compare is implemented in [`unicodeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/unicodeobject.c). After a few checks such as string length and "kind" (python may use 1, 2 or 4 bytes per character depending on unicode USC character size), its just a call to the C lib `memcmp`.

With a quick change to your python code

```
condition = True
if len(s1) == len(s2):
    for x,y in zip(s1, s2):
        if x != y:
            condition = False
            break
else:
    condition = False
```

the python code has the same O(n) time complexity as memcmp, its just that python has a much bigger O. Time complexity doesn't say anything about how long an operation takes, just how an operation scales with a larger input set `n`.

`memcmp` is much faster than the python version because of inherent language overhead. But it scales the same. And when you think about it, each of the `if x != y:` compares in the second example runs the exact same code as the single `s1 == s2` compare in the first.

Comment: Small detail: your logic is backwards: when `len(s1) != len(s2)`, you should immediately set `condition = False` without inspecting the contents, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

A simple test:

```py
s1 = "a"
s2 = "aa"
condition= True
for x,y in zip(s1, s2):
    if x != y:
        condition = False 
print(condition) # True
```

show that your assumption is incorrect.
Otherwise, python `==` is very efficient, so you can assume it's at worse O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how it's implemented, the comparison of two strings is going to take O(n) time. (There might exist pre-built side data structures that could help speed it up, but I'm assuming your input is just two strings and nothing else.)

Yes, the C implementation that `==` ends up calling is much faster, because it's in C rather than as a Python loop, but its worse-case big-Oh complexity is still going to be O(n).

PS: as @AdvMaple pointed out, your alternative implementation is wrong, because `zip` stops as soon as one of its input runs out of elements, but that does not change the time-complexity question.